# ERROR: update or delete on table "tb_webapp" violates foreign key constraint on table "tb_database"

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, maven, jpa

I'm trying to delete the parent student or parent course and I get this error:
update or delete on table "tb_webapp" violates foreign key constraint "fkkp7x1km86fdyb6c1jdc4u3phg" on table "tb_database"
Detail: Key (id_webapp)=(4) is still referenced from table "tb_database".

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: JDBC exception executing SQL [delete from tb_webapp where uuid=?] [ERROR: update or delete on table "tb_webapp" violates foreign key constraint "fkkp7x1km86fdyb6c1jdc4u3phg" on table "tb_database"Detail: Key (id_webapp)=(4) is still referenced from table "tb_database".] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]; constraint [fkkp7x1km86fdyb6c1jdc4u3phg]] with root cause
```

`Controller "WebAppController"`:

```
@DeleteMapping("/{uuid}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteWebAppByUuid(
            @PathVariable("uuid") UUID uuid
    ) {
        try {
            WebAppEntity result = webAppService.deleteWebAppByUuid(uuid);
            ApiResponse<WebAppEntity> response = new ApiResponse<>(HttpStatus.OK, "Success delete data web app!", result);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(response, response.getStatus());
        } catch (CustomRequestException error) {
            return error.GlobalCustomRequestException(error.getMessage(), error.getStatus());
        }
    }
```

`Services "WebAppService"`:

```
@Transactional
    public WebAppEntity deleteWebAppByUuid(UUID uuid) {
        WebAppEntity findData = webAppRepository.findByUuid(uuid);
        int result = webAppRepository.findByUuidAndDelete(uuid);
        if (result > 0) {
            return findData;
        } else {
            throw new CustomRequestException("UUID " + uuid + " not found", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
    }
```

`Entity "WebAppEntity"`

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "webAppEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<DatabaseEntity> databaseList;
```

`Entity "DatabaseEntity"`

````
package sda.catalogue.sdacataloguerestapi.modules.WebApp.Entities;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UuidGenerator;
import sda.catalogue.sdacataloguerestapi.modules.TypeDatabase.Entities.TypeDatabaseEntity;

import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
@Immutable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "tb_database")
public class DatabaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_database")
    private long idDatabase;

    @UuidGenerator
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID uuid;

    @Column(name = "api_name")
    private String apiName;

    @Column(name = "ip_address")
    private String apiAddress;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_webapp")
    @JsonIgnore
    private WebAppEntity webAppEntity;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_type_database")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("databaseEntities")
    private TypeDatabaseEntity typeDat```
````

`` `Repository "WebAppRepository"` ``

```
@Modifying@Transactional@Query("DELETE FROM WebAppEntity w WHERE w.uuid = :uuid")int findByUuidAndDelete(UUID uuid);
```

postman log :   "status": 500, "error": "Internal Server Error",    I wanna try delete by uuid from parent: tb_WebApp, and automatically delete from child: tb_database